# How do you use Google Drive API to permanently authorize an user account to upload files to your Drive?

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

I am trying to get my web application to use a dedicated email account to upload files to google drive through the API. The problem being that it keeps requiring the potential users to authenticate the account that I prepared for it, which is exactly what I am trying to prevent the need for.

Any solutions I came across directed me at using the refresh token to ensure the account stays authorized. This still comes with the issue that on the first time use, an user has to authenticate said account. Saving the access token with the refresh token locally didn't work, as it still forced new users to authenticate.
the snippet below displays the code used to authenticate.

```
class AccessDrive
{
    private $client;

    //initialize the client data provided on the call of the function
    private function initClient($scopes, $clientsecret, $returnUrl)
    {
        $client = new Google_Client();
        try{$client->setAuthConfig($clientsecret);}catch(Google_Exception $e){echo $e;}
        $client->setClientId(CLIENT_ID);
        $client->setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME);
        $client->setAccessType('offline');
        //$client->setApprovalPrompt('force');
        $client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);   // incremental auth
        foreach ($scopes as $scope) { 
            $client->addScope($this->getScope($scope)); //assume one or multiple from the google drive scopes
        }
        $client->setRedirectUri( $returnUrl);
        return $client;
    }

    public function Login()
    {
        if (!$_SESSION['code']) {
            $auth_url = $this->client->createAuthUrl();
            header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
        } else {
            error_reporting(-1 & ~E_WARNING);
            $this->client->authenticate($_SESSION['code']);
        }
        return false;
    } 

    public function __construct($returnUrl, $scopes, $clientSecret)
    {
        $this->client = $this->initClient($scopes, $clientSecret, $returnUrl);
        $this->Login();
    }
}
?>
```

How does one make sure that the application will not need to prompt users to authenticate, staying authenticated outside the functionality the user is supposed to access?

--> Edit:
After attempting to implement the suggested method, by DaImTo, the following code generates a Google_Service_Exception, stating that the client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens with this method. I am not sure where that goes wrong.

```
class AccessDrive
{
    private $client;

    public function __construct( $scopes, $credentials, $email, $toImpersonate )
    {
        putenv( "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=".$credentials);
        $scopelist =[];
        foreach ($scopes as $scope) {
            array_push($scopelist, $this->getScope($scope));
        }
        $client = new Google_Client();
        $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
        $client->addScope($scopelist);
        $client->setSubject($toImpersonate);
        $this->client = $client;
    }
```

--> Edit:
If you downvote, I would like to know why so I can improve my current and future questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are currently authencating using Oauth2.  Oauth2 allows you to request access from a user to access their google drive account.   Assuming they grant you access you are given an access token which allows you to access their data for an hour.   If you request offline access you will be given a refresh token which you can use to request a new access token when ever the access token expires.

In your case becouse you are trying to access your own drive account always i sugest you look into using a service account instead.   Service accounts are pre approved you share a folder on your google drive account with it and it will have access to that drive account as long as you dont remove the permissions.  I have a post about how service accounts work [Google developer for beginners service account](http://www.daimto.com/google-developer-console-service-account/)

Example:

```
// Load the Google API PHP Client Library.
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
// Use the developers console and download your service account
// credentials in JSON format. Place the file in this directory or
// change the key file location if necessary.
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='.__DIR__.'/service-account.json');
/**
 * Gets the Google client refreshing auth if needed.
 * Documentation: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount
 * Initializes a client object.
 * @return A google client object.
 */
function getGoogleClient() {
    return getServiceAccountClient();
}
/**
 * Builds the Google client object.
 * Documentation: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/service-accounts
 * Scopes will need to be changed depending upon the API's being accessed. 
 * array(Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_READONLY, Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS)
 * List of Google Scopes: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes
 * @return A google client object.
 */
function getServiceAccountClient() {
    try {   
        // Create and configure a new client object.        
        $client = new Google_Client();
        $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
        $client->addScope([YOUR SCOPES HERE]);
        return $client;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

code ripped form my sample project [serviceaccount.php](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-APIs-PHP-Samples/blob/master/Samples/Drive%20API/v3/ServiceAccount.php)

Usage:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
session_start();
require_once __DIR__ . '/ServiceAccount.php';     
$client = getGoogleClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
```

All your requests then get sent using `$service`

Comment: first of all, thank you a lot for your answer, a service account is definitely the way to go. However it lands me with a Google Service Exception i haven't quite been able to work out since. It states that my client is not authorized to retrieve accesstokens in this method. Do you think i missed something? I have placed the new snippet in the answer.

Comment: IN google developer console make sure you created a client type service account.   There is a diffrence in the types of clients that you can create.

Comment: i can choose several roles, but it doesn't let me choose a type of service account. the documentation on this sort of thing is extremely unclear to me, and maybe i'm missing something, but even after adding several different roles to try and get something to happen, i'm still lost on how to get this working.

Comment: You are doing this in the Google Developer console right?  https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials  There is nothing about roles there.  click create credentials  -> service account key

Comment: yes, i am doing it in the console. i've tried that but it still won't let me access Google Drive through my application, giving off that same error. I also shared the folder in drive i am supposed to access. Makes me think i lack some sort of permission, or something is off with my code

Comment: What error are you getting? And what scope did you set?

Comment: i'm currently using this scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file
as for the error, it is described above, but i'll past the exact one here
Fatal error: Uncaught Google_Service_Exception: { "error": "unauthorized_client", "error_description": "Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method." } in D:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Http\REST.php on line 118

Comment: I think you should download the service account file again from Google developer console.  I suspect that you using the wrong one.    That message means the client you are using is not a service account client.  make sure GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS is pointing to the corect file.